# Is it possible to export table with 15 columns without breaking the layout in jsPDF autoTable?

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I tried to export 15 columns with jsPDF autoTable, but the exported table layout is not readable. How can we achieve it?

Comment: How would you for it to be displayed? Smaller font?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had 10 columns and I changed pdf orientation to `'landscape'` and styles. Also, if you have long text in columns you need to enable `overflow: 'linebreak'`.
Here some code example:

```
const doc = new jsPDF({ orientation: 'landscape' });

doc.text('Transitions', 5, 12);
doc.autoTable({
    showHead: 'firstPage',
    columns: // your columns,
    body: // your rows,
    startY: 18,
    styles: { overflow: 'linebreak', cellWidth: 'wrap', cellPadding: 1, fontSize: 6 },
    columnStyles: { text: { cellWidth: 'auto' } }
});
```

if you need to use linebreak for specific column:

```
doc.autoTable({
    showHead: 'firstPage',
    columns: // your columns,
    body: // your rows,
    startY: 18,
    styles: { overflow: 'linebreak', cellWidth: 'wrap', cellPadding: 1, fontSize: 6 },
    columnStyles: { 
        someColumnName1: { cellWidth: 'auto' },
        someColumnName2: { cellWidth: 'auto' } 
    }
});
```

`someColumnName1` - this is `dataKey` from `columns`.

Please provide your code or jsfiddle, so we can provide better solution.

Comment: Thanks @DenysM changing orientation and column width fixed the issue.